# VB.net : Can't connect to mysql (mariadb) with ssl enabled

Tags: mysql, vb.net, ssl, mariadb

Iam trying to connect my Winform app (VB.net, W10 computer with mysql connector 8.0.26) to a Mariadb database (On Debian 10) with **ssl enabled** but even after many search, i don't found solution.
**Without ssl** enabled, app run fine, no issue.

On same computer, i have DBeaver and ssl connection works fine with db. (PEM certificate)

I think my connection parameters is wrong but i don't find where...

I took an example from here : https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/ssl-with-a-file-based-certificate/

Maybe .pfx file can cause issue ? anyone could give me an example with PEM certificate.

In my app, error is auth failed ...

What CertificateFile path means ? i have stored D:\client.pfx on computer running app, is that ?

```
stringCmd = "SELECT name FROM hosts WHERE state = '0' AND enabled = '1'"
stringConn = "server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;user id=xxxxx;password=xxxxxxx;database=xxxxxxxxx;SSL Mode=Required;CertificateFile=D:\client.pfx;CertificatePassword=xxxxxxxxx"
myConn = New MySqlConnection(stringConn)
myCmd = New MySqlCommand(stringCmd, myConn)
myConn.Open()
```

[Stack Trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4kZN.jpg)

***EDIT 26/07:***

I stored certificat in windows certificat store and used `Certificate Store Location=CurrentUser;SslMode=Required`

I used also an other MysqlConnector (before Oracle Mysql Data Connector):
https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector

McAfee seems to block PEM certificat.

Now it works but it's very slow to initiate the first connection, after it seems ok. i have increased mysql timeout...

Comment: If the error is auth failed then this is unlikely to be a SSL problem. More likely the user/password combination, possibly the password for the certificate file. But you should have a more complete stack trace.

Comment: Without ssl and same user/password it works, Certificate password already checked.

Comment: Are you sure the connection string is correct ? I would expect Uid, Pwd... Check [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/) for examples.

Comment: no i'm not sure about connection string, yes in your example it's not exactly same but i think it's equivalent because with SSL Mode=None, it works fine. I would like to try with PEM file but all example found don't work also ...

Comment: Dump the full error message. There has to be more details than that.

Comment: i have edited my post with stack trace image

Comment: Please do not post images, post text. But are you sure sure the stack trace is complete ?

Comment: Mysql log give me this error :2021-07-26 12:48:41 87 [Warning] Aborted connection 87 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (This connection closed normally without authentication)

Comment: It's very possible that your **firewall** is interfering with the connection. Try to disable it and see what happens. If the firewall is indeed the problem then you need to add a proper rule. Although that doesn't explain why DBeaver works with SSL on the same machine. Since MariaDB is a **fork** of Mysql you need to make sure that your **driver** is appropriate. What you are using is in fact this [one](https://mysqlconnector.net/), and it is supposed to work with MariaDB.

Comment: Thanks You for your help, i've found a solution, see below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many search, i have found a solution. I hope to help others admins.
Now, all connectors works fine (Oracle etc..).

It was a Windows settings which need to be modified :

1. Press Win+R to open the "Run" dialog
2. Type "gpedit.msc" (without quotes) and press Enter
3. In the "Local Group Policy Editor", expand "Computer Configuration", expand "Administrative Templates", expand "System", expand "Internet Communication Management", and then click "Internet Communication settings".
4. In the details panel, double-click "Turn off Automatic Root Certificates Update", click Enabled, then click OK. This change will be effective immediatelly without restart.